# Why should we perform cosine normalization for SVM feature vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, svm

I was recently playing around with the well known movie review dataset used in binary sentiment analysis. It consists of 1,000 positive and 1,000 negative reviews. While exploring various feature-encodings with unigram features, I noticed that all previous research publications normalize the vectors by their Euclidean norm in order to scale them to unit-length.

In my experiments using Liblinear, however, I found that such length-normalization decreases the classification accuracy significantly. I studied the vectors, and I think this is the reason: the dimension of the vector space is, say, 10,000. As a result, the Euclidean norm of the vectors is very high compared to the individual projections. Therefore, after normalization, all the vectors get very small numbers on each axis (i.e., the projection on an axis).

This surprised me, because all publications in this field claim that they perform cosine normalization, whereas I found that NOT normalizing yields better classification.

Thus my question: is there any specific disadvantage if we don't perform cosine normalization for SVM feature vectors? (Basically, I am seeking a mathematical explanation for this need for normalization).

Comment: In low-dimensional spaces, normalization has the disadvantage of reducing the dimension by one. But this reduction should not matter in high dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After perusing the manual of LibSVM, I realize why the normalization was yielding much lower accuracy when compared to *not* normalizing. They recommend scaling the data to a [0,1] or [-1,1] interval. This is something I had not done. Scaling up will resolve the issue of having too many data points very close to zero, while retaining the advantages of length-normalization.